# Inserting into System Audit Fields in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce and need to migrate data from Legacy CRM into Salesforce. Question is, how do I populate system audit fields with legacy data especially "Create Date and Modified Date"?

Answer (score 3):

A few years back one of our users exported a mass amount of data from salesforce.com.  Eventually it needed to be moved back into salesforce.com.  What we did was contact salesforce.com support and request that the "edit audit fields" feature be activated for our org.  The feature was enabled for a few weeks and I was able to specify the CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate values for the data that was re-inserted.

[Salesforce.com System Fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/system_fields.htm)

Answer (score 1):

With the Winter '16 release, you no longer need to contact salesforce to set audit fields on record creation. ([Release Notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_general_audit_fields_inactive_owners.htm))

You can enable it by going to: *Setup* > *Customize* > *User Interface* and selecting the checkbox for *Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions*.

Then you can assign that permission to a user through a permission set or profile.